# How do function arguments work in python?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I started coding 2 days back and just for some practice i decided to make a calculator. It keeps giving me errors saying num1 is not defined.

```
#data collection
def a1(num1, op, num2) :
 num1 = int[input("enter the first number: ")]
 op = input("enter the operation: ") 
 num2 = int[input("enter the second number: ")]


#running the operations
def a2() :
 if (op == "+"):
  num3 = num1 + num2
  print (num3)
 elif (op == "-"):
  num4 = num1 - num2
  print (num4)
 elif (op == "*"):
  num5 = num1 * num2
  print (num5)
 elif (op == "/"):
  num6 = num1 / num2
  print (num6)
 else:
  a1(num1, op, num2)
  a2()
a1(num1, op, num2)
a2()
```

Answer (score 1):

Function arguments are positional variables. You need to call the function and pass it the variables in order for it to work.

Variables passed to a function are local, only usable in the function. You want to either change a global variable or return from that function.

What your code is doing is passing unassigned variable names num1, op, num2 to a function.

Read more here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to fix up your existing code:

```
#data collection
def a1():
    num1 = int(input("enter the first number: "))
    op = input("enter the operation: ") 
    num2 = int(input("enter the second number: "))
    return num1, op, num2

#running the operations
def a2(num1, op, num2):
    if (op == "+"):
        num3 = num1 + num2
        print(num3)
    elif (op == "-"):
        num4 = num1 - num2
        print(num4)
    elif (op == "*"):
        num5 = num1 * num2
        print (num5)
    elif (op == "/"):
        num6 = num1 / num2
        print(num6)
    else:
        num1, op, num2 = a1()
        a2(num1, op, num2)

num1, op, num2 = a1()
a2(num1, op, num2)
```

The changes I made:

1. Make `a1` not take any parameters but instead return three values.
2. Make callers of `a1` capture the returned values into local variables.
3. Make `a2` accept three parameters.
4. Change `int[...]` to `int(...)`.
5. Fix up some indentation and spaces to conform with typical Python style.

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines:

```
a1(num1, op, num2)
a2()
```

are the "main" body of your program.  Before that are two function definitions.  When you invoke `a1`, what is the value of `num1`?  Indeed, what is its type?  Answer: it's a name with no value associated with it.  That's why the Python interpreter complains.